# FluentValidation Transform

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I would like to use FluentValidation to change the format of an input based on a second value

The example in the FluentValidation documentation I am following is:  (although my values are all strings)

```
Transform(x => x.SomeStringProperty, StringToNullableInt)
    .GreaterThan(10);

int? StringToNullableInt(string value)
  => int.TryParse(value, out int val) ? (int?) val : null;
```

My method the Transform would call is:

```
public static string FormatPostCode(string postcode, string countryCode)
```

How do I pass the countryCode in the Transform statement?

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem? or you found out the solution by yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both `PostCode` and `CountryCode` are properties of your `Class`

The `Transform` statement would look like

```
Transform(x => x, x => FormatPostCode(x.PostCode, x.CountryCode));
```